# How to remove Exception, The getter 'index was called on null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Iam new to using BLoC or state management, in my case i using BLoC to navigate my another screen with button in Navigation Rail. this is my code

> class navigation_bloc

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

enum Navigation{HOME, SCAN}

    class NavigationBloc {
      final BehaviorSubject<Navigation> _navigationController =
          BehaviorSubject.seeded(Navigation.HOME);
    
      Stream<Navigation> get currentNavigationIndex => _navigationController.stream;
    
      void changeNavigationIndex(final Navigation option) =>
          _navigationController.sink.add(option);
    
      void dispose() => _navigationController?.close();
    }
```

> class navigation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aplicationsc/page/homepage/homepage.dart';
import 'package:aplicationsc/page/scanpage/scanpage.dart';
import 'package:aplicationsc/structure/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'package:aplicationsc/page/aboutpage/aboutpage.dart';

import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class NavStructure extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavStructureState createState() => _NavStructureState();
}

class _NavStructureState extends State<NavStructure> {
  final NavigationBloc bloc = new NavigationBloc();
  int _selectedIndex;
  
   @override
   void dispose() {
     bloc.dispose();
     super.dispose();
   }

  NavigationRailDestination textDestination(String text) {
    return NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
      label: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        child: RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: -1,
          child: Text(text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(99, 72, 50, 0.1),
        body: StreamBuilder<Navigation>(
          stream: bloc.currentNavigationIndex,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            _selectedIndex = snapshot.data.index;

            return Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: snapshot.data == Navigation.HOME
                      ? HomePage(bloc: bloc)
                      : snapshot.data == Navigation.SCAN
                          ? ScanPage(bloc: bloc)
                          : null,
                ),
                NavigationRail(
                  selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                  onDestinationSelected: (i) =>
                      bloc.changeNavigationIndex(Navigation.values[i]),
                  minWidth: 50,
                  extended: false,
                  groupAlignment: 0.85,
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(43, 34, 34, 1.0),
                  labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                  selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 11.5.sp,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    decorationThickness: 3.0,
                    decorationColor: Colors.brown[400],
                    decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
                  ),
                  unselectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.brown[400],
                    fontSize: 11.5.sp,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                  ),
                  destinations: [
                    textDestination("HOME"),
                    textDestination("SCAN"),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but i always get Exeption

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<Navigation>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<Navigation, AsyncSnapshot<Navigation>>#08ee6):
The getter 'index' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: index

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<Navigation> file:///Z:/AndroidStudioProject/aplicationsc/lib/structure/navigation.dart:56:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _NavStructureState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:aplicationsc/structure/navigation.dart:60:44)
#2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:545:81)
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
...
====================================================================================================
```

my code work finely without error. Can I remove the Exception that appears in this case? or How can i calling index to remove this null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the issue:

```dart
_selectedIndex = snapshot.data.index;
```

In the `builder`, you need to first check if there's some data and then proceed to the `index`. Something like this:

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    _selectedIndex = snapshot.data.index;
    return Row(...); // Your code. 
  }
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // Newly added. 
}
```

Comment: thanks before, but I got a new Exception with that code. "Failed assertion: line 146 pos 16: 'selectedIndex != null': is not true."

Comment: Can you tell me what `print(snapshot.data.runtimeType)` shows?

Comment: the output
I/flutter ( 9152): Navigation
I/chatty  ( 9152): uid=10085(com.septiandika.aplicationsc) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 9152): Navigation

Comment: After writing above code, use `print(_selectedIndex)`, does it show `null`? Your code isn't reproducible otherwise I wouldn't be asking for print statements ;)

Comment: my _selectedIndex is 0 value, is that null? || output  I/flutter ( 9152): Navigation
I/flutter ( 9152): 0
I/flutter ( 9152): Navigation
I/flutter ( 9152): 0
I/flutter ( 9152): Navigation
I/flutter ( 9152): 0

Comment: No, `0` isn't `null`. That part seems fine. Ahh I see what the problem is, you forgot to use `if-else` block.  Let me update the post.